# "car hooks up" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases

"The car hooks up really fast, grabs that road, and just propels us forward."

What does "hook up" mean in this sentence?

The sentence is spoken by a man who runs a test driving of a certain brand of a car. And he said this during his drive on the track.

Comment: More context is needed.

Comment: It sounds like he's using a metaphor. Imagine the car throwing out a grappling hook. The hook grabs the road, and pressing the accelerator reels the car quickly to the part of the road it grabbed. So basically, the car accelerates quickly.

Comment: @Lawrence - Are you sure it doesn't mean that the car attracts girls?

Comment: @HotLicks That interpretation hadn’t occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

The additional context doesn't really point us towards anything specific. As I understand it, it just means it is quick off the mark (i.e. reaches top speed quickly). I don't see it as a common usage of "hook up", which is more often seen in other contexts.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-quick-slow-off-the-mark

Answer (score 1):

There is a relevant definition in

[**Glossary of motorsport terms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_motorsport_terms#H)

> **Hook up** (drag racing)
>
> Good traction between tires and track resulting in increased acceleration and reduced slipping or smoking of tires.